# xamarin, android, switching between activities, login page, intent

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent

I am new with Xamarin and I am trying to create my first application with Authentication and Authorization service.

My first **MainActivity** is actually the Login/Sign up page.
I have managed to do the link between the Main activity with the second one, which is the **SignUpActivity**, but I need the same reference for the **LoginActivity**.

> First problem:

If I create the activities with different name than Activity1/2/3/etc..
it throws the **Unhandled Exception:**

> **Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Timeout exceeded getting exception details**

Why does it have problem with the names?

> Second problem:

```
     public class MainActivity : Activity
        {
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
            Button button;

            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

                //  var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.logo);
                //  var userNameText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.username);
                //  var passwordText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.password);
                button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.login);
                //  var forgotPassword = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.forgotPassword);

                relativeLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.mainBackground);
                button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.signup);
                button.Click += signUpButton_Click;
                button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.login);
                button.Click += loginButton_Click;
                relativeLayout.Click += relative_Click;
            }

            void signUpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
---------->     Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity2));
                this.StartActivity(intent);
            }

            void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
---------->     Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity3));
                this.StartActivity(intent);
            }

            void relative_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
            {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)this.GetSystemService(Activity.InputMethodService);
                inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.CurrentFocus.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
            }
        }
```

> it throws the same Unhandled Exception:
>    **Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Timeout exceeded getting exception details**

Why does it work only with one activity but not with another?
I have test it with **Activity2** and it works.
Then I were recreating all over again the UI file and the .cs file of the **Activity3**, but I have the same issue.

Could you give me some directions how to switch between more activities?
Anything will be helpful.

Comment: Which attributes are you using on your Activities?

Comment: public class Activity2 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Activity2);
            // Create your application here
        }
    }

Comment: No, those are not attributes :) They usually look like `[Activity(Label = "MyActivityName")]`

Comment: Activity2 and Activity3, sorry.

Comment: So you don't have attributes on your Activities?

Comment: [Activity(Label = "Activity3")] and  [Activity(Label = "Activity2")]

Comment: Do you have any funny characters in your namespace? I can't reproduce your issue here.

Comment: No. I do not have